# Adding a comment when raising an issue in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

Using a plugin to raise issues such as: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/rules/CreateIssuesOnJavaFilesSensor.java

I want to be able to add a comment to the issue when I raise it, is this possible?

Alternitivly is there a way within a plugin to add comments as a post process or do I have to do it through the web api?